# roo sample gwtNoEntities fails to load

Tags: gwt, spring-roo

I've just tried the the gwtNoEntities sample that is bundled with roo-1.1.0.

when launching using tomcat:run, or jetty:run, I get only the loading box.

When running it in GWT hosted mode, I get the following stacktrace reported in the client,
this appears to be an error related to setting up the default place using browser history, which is empty.

What would be the correct way to go about fixing this?

**stacktrace**

```
    00:02:08.323 [ERROR] Unable to load module entry point class com.springsource.foo.client.scaffold.Scaffold (see associated exception for details)
    java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:796)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:828)
at com.springsource.foo.client.scaffold.ScaffoldDesktopApp.init(ScaffoldDesktopApp.java:139) 
at com.springsource.foo.client.scaffold.ScaffoldDesktopApp.run(ScaffoldDesktopApp.java:61)
at com.springsource.foo.client.scaffold.Scaffold.onModuleLoad(Scaffold.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:183)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

**generated code in question**

```
/* Browser history integration */
ScaffoldPlaceHistoryMapper mapper = GWT.create(ScaffoldPlaceHistoryMapper.class);
mapper.setFactory(placeHistoryFactory);
PlaceHistoryHandler placeHistoryHandler = new PlaceHistoryHandler(mapper);
/* 139 */ ProxyListPlace defaultPlace = getTopPlaces().iterator().next();
placeHistoryHandler.register(placeController, eventBus, defaultPlace);
placeHistoryHandler.handleCurrentHistory();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace the generated code with while condition block at the below (line 139)

```
    while (getTopPlaces().iterator().hasNext()) {
    ProxyListPlace defaultPlace = getTopPlaces().iterator().next();
    placeHistoryHandler.register(placeController, eventBus, defaultPlace);
    placeHistoryHandler.handleCurrentHistory();
}
```

recompile with mvn compile, restart with mvn gwt:run. Now you should have no error but with empty page.

The gwtNoEntities.roo example has no data. You may try other example like expenses.roo. The generated code should be okay.

Please remember to accept the answer if it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: The fix worked, but the GWT client is only rendered when I run it from mvn gwt:run, not from mvn tomcat:run or mvn jetty:run. I tried using firefox-3 and IE-7.